# String vector with user input

Tags: c#

Stuck for hours on this task. I really appreciate help, it is not shown in the literature how this is to be done. I can create the vector but after that I'm totally blocked.

> Create a string vector with five elements. The user will then enter 5 names via a for loop. The program then writes these names via another for loop.

Please type out the code so I can understand. Without solving this first task I can't do the other ones.

Here's my futile attempt so far

```
int [] namn = new int [5];

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++);
{
Console.Write("Ange fem namn");
string str = Console.ReadLine();
int names = Convert.ToInt32(str); 
}
```

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: Please, provide *your attempts* and we will help with errors.

Comment: I think people here are quite open to helping with homework/learning - but you at least need to have an attempt at it yourself first.

Comment: @Jamiec just wait until some rep hunter comes in. 5 minutes already, I assume we should have an answer soon.

Comment: @NullException hey Im one of those rep hunters :) But its 17:00 on a Friday and... meh beer o'clock.

Comment: Does the question define what a vector is? In standard .Net a "string vector" is not a thing.

Comment: Added the code so far.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the *main* (and the *most difficult* error to find) is `;` after `for` loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++);
```

this loop does *nothing* five times.

```
//DONE: "string[]" - Create a STRING vector with five elements... 
string [] namn = new string [5];

//DONE: namn.Length - no magic numbers (5)
for (int i = 0; i < namn.Length; i++) // !!! no ";" !!!
{
   Console.Write("Ange fem namn");
   //DONE: put into array, not to a local variable
   namn[i] = Console.ReadLine();
}

// Print out the names
foreach(var item in namn)
  Console.WriteLine(item);
```